# Sending Amplify access token to server via Apollo Client

Tags: amazon-cognito, apollo-client, apollo-server, aws-amplify

How to use Apollo Client to send an asynchronously fetched JWT access token from AWS Amplify (Cognito) to the Apollo server for backend validation.

Figured it out if anyone else needs it.

Why not use Appsync? as of 9/11/21 it doesn't implement enough of the GraphQL specification for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I am using React-native expo and am loading my graphql endpoint url using [react-native-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv).

```
import {
  ApolloClient, ApolloLink, HttpLink, InMemoryCache
} from "@apollo/client"
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context'
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth"
import { ENDPOINT } from "@env"

if (!ENDPOINT) {
  throw new Error("Need env ENDPOINT")
}

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT })

const authMiddleware = setContext(async (_, { headers }) => {
  try {
    const currentSession = await Auth.currentSession()
    const accessToken = currentSession.getAccessToken()
    const token = accessToken.getJwtToken()
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        authorization: token || null,
      },
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      headers,
    }
  }
})

const link = ApolloLink.from([
  authMiddleware,
  httpLink
])

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
})
```